Using el-radio-group, there is an issue with the options having duplicate tabindex, causing the options to not be correctly selected
I set up two columns in el-table: odIsDis and odIsReturn. These two columns can be dynamically modified using el-radio-group. By modifying the odIsDis options to disable and assign values to the odIsReturn options before selecting odIsReturn, not only does the assignment fail, but after re-enabling odIsReturn, its options cannot be directly modified by clicking.
Here's my code:
        <el-table-column prop="odIsDis" width="110">
          <template v-slot="{ row }">
            <el-radio-group v-model="row.odIsDis" @change="handleIsDisChange(row)">
              <el-radio :label="1">yes</el-radio>
              <el-radio :label="0">no</el-radio>
            </el-radio-group>
          </template>
        </el-table-column>
        <el-table-column prop="odIsReturn" width="110">
          <template v-slot="{ row }">
            <el-radio-group v-model="row.odIsReturn" :disabled="!row.odIsDis&&row.odIsDis!==null">
              <el-radio :label="1">yes</el-radio>
              <el-radio :label="0">no</el-radio>
            </el-radio-group>
          </template>
        </el-table-column>


  handleIsDisChange(item: IInstrumentEquipmentGood) {
    if (!item.odIsDis) {
      item.odIsReturn = 0
    }
  }

Simply put, if odIsReturn is disabled before it is clicked, it can no longer be properly clicked and assigned values.
Ask ChatGPT, it replied: This issue appears to be due to the el-radio-group component not properly updating and rendering when the disabled state changes. Setting a dynamic key can fix this bug. I tried this approach, and it solved the problem, but I don't understand the underlying principle. I want to know the specific reason why this bug occurred and if there are better solutions.

It is caused by the fact that two data are not initialized, but the specific reasons need to be further studied, but initializing tableData is a better solution.
